# Terraform iterate through list within a map of objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, for-loop, go, terraform, devops

I am seeking help with iterating through lists within a map of objects.

This is my current map:

```
       test125231-test-tunnel   = {
           authby        = "secret"
           auto          = "ondemand"
           customer_name = "test125231"
           dh_ingress_ip = "10.0.1.71"
           esp           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
           ike           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
           ikelifetime   = 3600
           ikev2         = "no"
           keyexchange   = "ike"
           left          = "%defaultroute"
           leftid        = "10.10.10.10"
           leftsourceip  = "10.0.1.122"
           leftsubnet    = "10.0.0.0/16"
           peer_ip       = "10.10.10.10"
           ports         = [
               "7000",
               "7001",
            ]
           right         = "10.10.10.10"
           rightid       = "10.10.10.10"
           rightsourceip = "10.41.0.191"
           rightsubnet   = "10.41.0.0/16"
           salifetime    = 3600
           tunnel_name   = "test-tunnel"
        }
       test125231-test-tunnel-2 = {
           authby        = "secret"
           auto          = "ondemand"
           customer_name = "test125231"
           dh_ingress_ip = "10.0.1.71"
           esp           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
           ike           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
           ikelifetime   = 3600
           ikev2         = "no"
           keyexchange   = "ike"
           left          = "%defaultroute"
           leftid        = "3.229.37.95"
           leftsourceip  = "10.0.1.234"
           leftsubnet    = "184.72.223.116/32"
           peer_ip       = "10.10.10.10"
           ports         = [
               "7000",
            ]
           right         = "10.10.10.10"
           rightid       = "10.10.10.10"
           rightsourceip = "10.41.0.191"
           rightsubnet   = "10.41.0.0/16"
           salifetime    = 3600
           tunnel_name   = "test-tunnel-2"
        }
       test125231-test-tunnel-3 = {
           authby        = "secret"
           auto          = "ondemand"
           customer_name = "test125231"
           dh_ingress_ip = "10.0.1.71"
           esp           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
           ike           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
           ikelifetime   = 3600
           ikev2         = "no"
           keyexchange   = "ike"
           left          = "%defaultroute"
           leftid        = "10.10.10.10"
           leftsourceip  = "10.0.1.234"
           leftsubnet    = "190.72.224.115/32"
           peer_ip       = "10.10.10.10"
           ports         = [
               "7000",
            ]
           right         = "10.10.10.10"
           rightid       = "10.10.10.10"
           rightsourceip = "10.41.0.191"
           rightsubnet   = "10.41.0.0/16"
           salifetime    = 3600
           tunnel_name   = "test-tunnel-3"
        }
       test125231-test-tunnel-4 = {
           authby        = "secret"
           auto          = "ondemand"
           customer_name = "test125231"
           dh_ingress_ip = "10.0.1.71"
           esp           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
           ike           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
           ikelifetime   = 3600
           ikev2         = "no"
           keyexchange   = "ike"
           left          = "%defaultroute"
           leftid        = "10.10.10.10"
           leftsourceip  = "10.0.1.234"
           leftsubnet    = "10.10.10.10/32"
           peer_ip       = "10.10.10.10"
           ports         = [
               "7000",
            ]
           right         = "10.10.10.10"
           rightid       = "10.10.10.10"
           rightsourceip = "10.41.0.191"
           rightsubnet   = "10.41.0.0/16"
           salifetime    = 3600
           tunnel_name   = "test-tunnel-4"
        }
    }
```

My end goal is to use a for each over each port in each lists.

I am using go templating in a terraform template file and this is what I currenlty have and it works for the index position of 0

```
%{ for key , value in tunnels }

-A PREROUTING  -s ${value.leftsourceip} -p tcp --dport ${value.ports[0]}  -j DNAT --to-destination  1.1.1.1:7000


%{ endfor ~}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been researching the merge function to see if its a good use case for this.

The end goal would be to have a separate dport rule for each port.

Comment: Please update the question with an example of what the ideal post-rendered template would appear like; especially wrt the values assigned to the `ports` key. Are you trying to render multiple `--dport` arguments in your command in your file?

Comment: I am trying to render multiple dport arguments in the file.

Comment: I've noticed that all almost your questions got answered yet only one  answer was ever accepted. Accepting useful answers is not only a good practice, but reduces duplicates and increases chances of your questions being actually answered.

Comment: apologies. I will accept previous answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to flatten the `tunnles`, and `merge` can be used for that:

```
variable "tunnels" {
    default =   {
      test125231-test-tunnel   = {
           authby        = "secret"
           auto          = "ondemand"
           customer_name = "test125231"
           dh_ingress_ip = "10.0.1.71"
           esp           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
           ike           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
           ikelifetime   = 3600
           ikev2         = "no"
           keyexchange   = "ike"
           left          = "%defaultroute"
           leftid        = "10.10.10.10"
           leftsourceip  = "10.0.1.122"
           leftsubnet    = "10.0.0.0/16"
           peer_ip       = "10.10.10.10"
           ports         = [
               "7000",
               "7001",
            ]
           right         = "10.10.10.10"
           rightid       = "10.10.10.10"
           rightsourceip = "10.41.0.191"
           rightsubnet   = "10.41.0.0/16"
           salifetime    = 3600
           tunnel_name   = "test-tunnel"
        },
       test125231-test-tunnel-2 = {
           authby        = "secret"
           auto          = "ondemand"
           customer_name = "test125231"
           dh_ingress_ip = "10.0.1.71"
           esp           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
           ike           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
           ikelifetime   = 3600
           ikev2         = "no"
           keyexchange   = "ike"
           left          = "%defaultroute"
           leftid        = "3.229.37.95"
           leftsourceip  = "10.0.1.234"
           leftsubnet    = "184.72.223.116/32"
           peer_ip       = "10.10.10.10"
           ports         = [
               "7000",
            ]
           right         = "10.10.10.10"
           rightid       = "10.10.10.10"
           rightsourceip = "10.41.0.191"
           rightsubnet   = "10.41.0.0/16"
           salifetime    = 3600
           tunnel_name   = "test-tunnel-2"
        },
       test125231-test-tunnel-3 = {
           authby        = "secret"
           auto          = "ondemand"
           customer_name = "test125231"
           dh_ingress_ip = "10.0.1.71"
           esp           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
           ike           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
           ikelifetime   = 3600
           ikev2         = "no"
           keyexchange   = "ike"
           left          = "%defaultroute"
           leftid        = "10.10.10.10"
           leftsourceip  = "10.0.1.234"
           leftsubnet    = "190.72.224.115/32"
           peer_ip       = "10.10.10.10"
           ports         = [
               "7000",
            ]
           right         = "10.10.10.10"
           rightid       = "10.10.10.10"
           rightsourceip = "10.41.0.191"
           rightsubnet   = "10.41.0.0/16"
           salifetime    = 3600
           tunnel_name   = "test-tunnel-3"
        },
       test125231-test-tunnel-4 = {
           authby        = "secret"
           auto          = "ondemand"
           customer_name = "test125231"
           dh_ingress_ip = "10.0.1.71"
           esp           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
           ike           = "aes256-sha256-modp2048"
           ikelifetime   = 3600
           ikev2         = "no"
           keyexchange   = "ike"
           left          = "%defaultroute"
           leftid        = "10.10.10.10"
           leftsourceip  = "10.0.1.234"
           leftsubnet    = "10.10.10.10/32"
           peer_ip       = "10.10.10.10"
           ports         = [
               "7000",
            ]
           right         = "10.10.10.10"
           rightid       = "10.10.10.10"
           rightsourceip = "10.41.0.191"
           rightsubnet   = "10.41.0.0/16"
           salifetime    = 3600
           tunnel_name   = "test-tunnel-4"
        }
    }
}







locals {
    tunnels_flat = merge([
           for tunnel_name, tunnel_details in var.tunnels:
            {
                for idx, port in tunnel_details.ports: 
                    "${tunnel_name}-${port}" => merge({                       
                        port          = port
                    }, tunnel_details)
            }
        ]...)
}
```

Then you will iterate (psudo-code):

```
%{ for key , value in local.tunnels_flat }

-A PREROUTING  -s ${value.leftsourceip} -p tcp --dport ${value.port}  -j DNAT --to-destination  1.1.1.1:7000


%{ endfor ~}
```

Comment: Thanks. You have helped me out with several of my questions and I am very grateful. Its helped me to better understand some of the more complicated loops

Comment: @JasonFrazee No problem. Glad the answer helped.